# Replace space-char by newline-char within max-line-length in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a python script, 
which breaks a continuous string into lines, 
when the `max_line_length` has been exceeded.

It shall not break words, 
and searches therefore the last occurrence of a whitespace-char,
which will be replaced by a newline-char.

For some reason it does not break within the specified limit.
E.g. when defining the `max_line_length = 80`, 
the text sometimes breaks at 82 or 83, etc.

Since quite some time I am trying to fix the problem, 
however it feels like i am having the tunnel vision 
and don't see the problem here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print('usage:   $ python3 breaktext.py <max_line_length> <file>')
    print('example: $ python3 breaktext.py 80 infile.txt')
    exit()

filename = str(sys.argv[2])
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    text_str = file.read().replace('\n', '')

    m = int(sys.argv[1])        # max_line_length
    text_list = list(text_str)  # convert string to list
    l = 0;                      # line_number
    i = m+1                     # line_character_index
    index = m+1                 # total_list_index
    while index < len(text_list):
        while text_list[l * m + i] != ' ':
            i -= 1
            pass
        text_list[l * m + i] = '\n'
        l += 1
        i = m+1
        index += m+1
        pass

    text_str = ''.join(text_list)
    print(text_str)
```

Comment: Why did you put the variable names in comments? Why convert a string to list, when you can just slice or index the string? Why are you assuming all lines are an equal length in `l * m`? I think that last one is a bit part of your problem, because there's no telling how far back `i` went before you skip ahead another `m` characters... it may well have split an earlier line again.

Comment: @YannVernier 1) Because literals make the code more readable than too long explanatory variable names. 2) I am used to work with pointers from `C`, in Python it is not possible to modify a string through indexing, however with lists it is. 3) What do you mean with assuming all lines are an equal length? There is just one very long line, which shall be formatted into several small ones.

Comment: The `textwrap` module of the stdlib will probably do what you want, with much less code on your part.

Comment: @PaulMcG `import textwrap` with `print(textwrap.fill(text_str, width=m))`  did the job, ty! Still I don't get what the problem is above :/

Answer (score 0):

I guess we'll take this from the top.

```
text_str = file.read().replace('\n', '')
```

Here's one assumption about the input data I don't know if it's true. You're replacing all the newline characters with nothing; if there weren't spaces next to them, this means the code below will never break the lines in the same places.

```
text_list = list(text_str)  # convert string to list
```

This splits the input file into single character strings. I guess you might have done so to make it mutable, such that you can replace individual characters, but it's a very expensive operation and loses all the features of a string. Python is a high level language that would allow you to split into e.g. words instead.

```
index = m+1                 # total_list_index
while index < len(text_list):
    #...
    index += m+1
```

Let's consider what this means. We're not entering into the loop if `index` exceeds the `text_list` length. But `index` is advancing in steps of `m+1`. So we're splitting `math.floor(len(text)/(max_line_length+1))` times. Unless *every* line is exactly `max_line_length` characters, not counting its space we replace with a newline, that's too few times. Too few times means too long lines, at least at the end.

```
l = 0;                      # line_number
i = m+1                     # line_character_index
#loop:
    while text_list[l * m + i] != ' ':
        i -= 1
    text_list[l * m + i] = '\n'
    l += 1
    i = m+1
```

This is making things difficult with index math. Quite clearly the one index we ever use is `l * m + i`. This moves in a quite odd way; it searches backwards for a space, then leaps forward as `l` increments and `i` resets. Whatever position it had reversed to is lost as all the leaps are in steps of `m`.

Let's apply `m=5` to the string `"Fee fie faw fum who did you see now"`. For the first iteration, `0 * 5 + 5+1` hits the second word, and `i` seeks back to the first space. The first line then is "Fee", as expected. The second search starts at `1*5 + 5+1`, which is a space, and the second line becomes "fie faw", which already exceeds our limit of 5! The reason is that `l * m` isn't the beginning of the line; it's actually in the middle of "fie", a discrepancy which can only grow as you continue through the file. It grows whenever you split off a line that is shorter than `m`.

The solution involves remembering where you did your split. That could be as simple as replacing `l * m` with `index`, and updating it by `index += i` instead of `m+1`.

Another odd effect happens if you ever encounter a word that exceeds the maximum line length. Beyond meaning a line is longer than the limit, `i` will still search backwards until it finds a space; that space could then be in an earlier line altogether, producing extra short lines as well as too long ones. That's a result of handling the entire text as one array and not limiting which section we're looking at.

Personally I'd much rather use Python's built in methods, such as [`str.rindex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex), which can find a particular character in a given region within a string:

```
s = "Fee fie faw fum who did you see now"
maxlen = 5
start = 8
end = s.rindex(' ', start, start+maxlen)
print(s[start:end])
start = end + 1
```

We also, as PaulMcG pointed out, can go full "batteries included" and use the standard library [textwrap module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) for the entire task.